# Finding a simple algorithm for an assignment problem

Tags: assignment-problem

I have an assignment problem where I need to assign resources to consumers. Each consumer has a list of resources it'd like to acquire, ordered by preference, and each consumer can have at most one resource. I'd like to find a mapping from the resources to the consumers that tries to satisfy each consumer's preferences.

The twist on the classic assignment problem here is that I'm not necessarily interested in an algorithm which produces the optimal solution. Rather, I'm interested in an algorithm that's simple enough a lay person could do it in their head, or at least part of it in their head at a time.

See, my resources and consumers are embedded in a (hex) grid where a resource and a consumer have to be on adjacent cells to be matched, so the graph is really quite sparse.  An ideal algorithm would only use "local" information, such as information about a cell and its neighbors.

An added wrinkle is that whatever algorithm should produce a stable result regardless of the choice of ordering the resources and consumers, either their inherant ordering or an algorithm-chosen ordering.  So just walking down the list of consumers from first to last, either their actual ordering or an invented ordering, giving them each their first pick of the remaining resources won't work, because the final assignments might change under a different ordering.

As an example of a possible algorithm, I could assign a resource only if there is exactly one consumer that wants that resource as its first choice, otherwise it doesn't get assigned. Certainly not perfect but it meets all the requirements above while giving a reasonable matching.

Are there any other algorithms worth considering here, or any relevant literature to read?

Comment: "explainability" is related to the black-box problem in modern ML, but instead of trying to explain to a software engineer we're aiming even lower and trying to explain to a lay person, and not just explain, but have a lay person make accurate predictions about what the results are going to be. An explainable solution is likely also a suboptimal solution, so there needs to be some wiggleroom on that account.  2. A randomly imposed ordering isn't going to predictable to a lay person.  3. I wasn't aware of the stable marriage problem; I'll see if there's relevant ideas I can use.

Comment: More like an algorithm that is simple enough you could run it in your head.

Comment: I've reworded the question.  Is it clearer now?

Comment: Looks great!  A quick check: if you sort the consumers by lexicographic order, then walk down them from first to last and assign each their first pick of the remaining resources, it sounds like that satisfies all of the stated requirements.  If you're not happy with that solution, maybe check whether there are any other requirements?

Comment: I specifically call that out: "An added wrinkle is that whatever algorithm should produce a stable result regardless of the ordering of the resources and consumers. So just walking down the list of consumers from first to last giving them each their first pick of the remaining resources won't work."

Comment: I don't see how that answers my question.  I did read that part of the question.  Did you notice the part about first sorting by lexicographic order? That ensures that the algorithm does produce a stable result (no matter what order the consumers are presented in, they'll be in the same order after sorting), and doesn't appear to have been considered in the question.

Comment: I've updated the question.  You're not allowed to have the final result change depending on the ordering, whether the given ordering or an invented one.  I don't necessarily know an elegant way of expressing that.